# Passing objects as WPARAM in window messages using smart pointers

Tags: c++, mfc, c++11

I am looking for a way to pass an object (`vector<long>` in my case) as a `WPARAM` in C++11 style.

The tutorials I found used a C-style cast or a `reinterpret_cast` to pass a pointer to the object. This requires that the recipient of the message properly disposes the object after receiving it.

Is there a way to pass the object using a `unique_ptr`? The recipient can take full ownership of the object.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130633/how-to-use-postthreadmessage-to-pass-a-struct/7130683#7130683.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a pointer to an object with a windows message then you need to ensure 2 things:

1. The source doesn't destroy the object before the message has been handled
2. The destination correctly destroys the object if necessary

If you know that the message will definitely be handled then you can call `.release()` on the source `unique_ptr` when sending the message, and then take ownership in the handler with another `unique_ptr`.

The problem comes with ensuring it is cleaned up if the message is NOT handled. This is tricky, as there isn't usually a clean way to check unless you use `SendMessage` (not `PostMessage`) and use the return value to communicate that the parameter has been claimed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such way. WPARAM is defined in the headers as UINT_PTR. It's simply a number that is big enough to accept a pointer in all architectures. The reason why you can pass a pointer with it is that pointers themselves are really just numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following trick: You allocate a `shared_ptr<>` *on heap* (!), pass the pointer to it as WPARAM, copy the `shared_ptr<>` on receive and delete the one which you got as `WPARAM`.